# Error occured while processing sync command

Tags: nullpointerexception, activemq-classic

I have a two machine setup with an ActiveMQ broker on each. Applications on both machines use the local broker to send status messages to each other. We were doing some testing to see the impact of network disconnect and reconnect on one machine, so we did network unplug and re-plug cycles on one machine (machine A) again and again with some delay (around 5 minutes delay). The brokers reconnected fine and applications were able to exchange status message on all but one such cycle. In the problem cycle machine A was unable to receive messages after network re-connect. On some investigation, we can see following exception in the machine B ActiveMQ logs.

```
2016-12-22 08:43:14,524 | DEBUG | Error occured while processing sync command: ConsumerInfo {commandId = 4, responseRequired = true, consumerId = CCM-UACSCHP002->CCM-UACSCHP001-64290-1482319725974-53:1:1:2, destination = topic://EEP, prefetchSize = 100, maximumPendingMessageLimit = 0, browser = false, dispatchAsync = true, selector = null, clientId = null, subscriptionName = NC-DS_CCM-UACSCHP002_EEP, noLocal = false, exclusive = false, retroactive = false, priority = 0, brokerPath = [ID:ccm-uacschp001-49159-1482188226837-0:1], optimizedAcknowledge = false, noRangeAcks = false, additionalPredicate = org.apache.activemq.command.NetworkBridgeFilter@e714024}, exception: java.lang.NullPointerException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Service | triggerStartAsyncNetworkBridgeCreation: remoteBroker=tcp://CCM-UACSCHP001/10.49.224.23:61616@65477, localBroker= vm://CCM-UACSCHP002#172
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.isAllowLinkStealing(TransportConnector.java:582)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.ConnectionContext.isAllowLinkStealing(ConnectionContext.java:337)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.TopicRegion.addConsumer(TopicRegion.java:128)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.addConsumer(RegionBroker.java:427)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConsumer(BrokerFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisoryBroker.addConsumer(AdvisoryBroker.java:128)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConsumer(BrokerFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConsumer(BrokerFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConsumer(BrokerFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addConsumer(MutableBrokerFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.util.LoggingBrokerPlugin.addConsumer(LoggingBrokerPlugin.java:186)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConsumer(BrokerFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addConsumer(MutableBrokerFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConsumer(TransportConnection.java:671)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerInfo.visit(ConsumerInfo.java:351)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:338)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:188)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onCommand(ResponseCorrelator.java:116)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.doDispatch(VMTransport.java:162)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.dispatch(VMTransport.java:154)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.oneway(VMTransport.java:131)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.addSubscription(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:920)
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DurableConduitBridge.setupStaticDestinations(DurableConduitBridge.java:79)
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.doStartLocalAndRemoteBridges(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:436)
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.access$500(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:105)
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport$5.run(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:336)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This exception appears in machine B ActiveMQ logs shortly after the network of machine A is re-connected.

Does this point to an obvious issue or do I need to provide more details for this issue?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

**Edited:**

ActiveMQ version is 5.13.2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Always provide the broker version.

Comment: I'd recommend more detail where possible. I highly recommend examining a packet capture to see what is being sent when this error occurs. It is also possible you may have found an uncaught exception which should have been handled with an appropriate error message. We can only tell with more info.

Comment: @TimBish: I have added ActiveMQ version (5.13.2).

Comment: @JoshuaBriefman The problem is that the issue is happening on a customer site. I am unable to re-produce it even when I use same steps as the customer. What other details can I provide to help narrow down the scope of this issue?

Comment: Anyone who can provide some feedback on this?